# Customize Vaadin Details Expand Icon by overriding default css applied on it

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I want expand/ unexpand feature and I use Vaadin Details for it.

```
Div contentDiv = new Div();

Label label = new Label("Expand");

Details details = new Details(label, contentDiv);
```

What it gives is following output:

[image]

But, what I want is the expand icon in right side. So for this I use **ThemeVariants** like this:

```
details.addThemeVariants(DetailsVariant.REVERSE);
```

What it gives is the following output:

[image]

There is huge gap between the text and Icon.

This is because of the below default css applied on it.

```
:host([theme~="reverse"]) [part="summary"] {
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

So, Now I need to override this css. And what I have done is added below css code in my css file and added `themeFor="summary"` in import. But it did not work.

```
:host([theme~="reverse"]) [part="summary"] {
            justify-content: normal;
        }
```

**Expected Output:**

[image]

So, is there any other way to do this in Vaadin? Or how can I override the default css of **ThemeVariants**.

**Note: I am using Vaadin 14.**

Comment: This is the [commit](https://github.com/anton415/vaadin-todo/commit/674dc6e67d109dbb9acfb7de9bf72ee85da762ab) where I got your expected result. Please, look how I import css file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the problem, when css did not work is wrong import.

Check if your css import specified with themeFor.

Example of css import:

```
@CssImport(value = "./styles/vaadin-details.css", themeFor = "vaadin-details")
```

In vaadin-details.css:

```
:host([theme~="reverse"]) [part="summary"] {
    justify-content: normal;
}
```

[Link to Vaadin documentation about css styling](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/charts/java-api/css-styling).

This is the [commit](https://github.com/anton415/vaadin-todo/commit/674dc6e67d109dbb9acfb7de9bf72ee85da762ab) where I got your expected result. Please, look how I import css file.

Also, as you correctly noted, this defect is reproduced when working with Div, not with Vertical Layout.

Comment: You can also use the same system ad add some padding arround the expand button, especially when using it in reverse mode

Answer (score 2):

Use `themeFor="vaadin-details"` instead of `themeFor="summary"` and it should work.

Also, use `justify-content: start;`. There’s no `normal` value for that property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content